# Getting Spring/Jackson to intelligently deserialize model subclasses

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Given a model hierarchy like so:

```
// WARNING: This is pseudo-code for giving an example!
public abstract class BaseVehicle {
    private String make;
    private String model;

    // Constructors, getters & setters down here
}

public class Motorcycle extends BaseVehicle {
    private int numCylinders;

    // Constructors, getters & setters down here
}

public class Car extends BaseVehicle {
    // ...etc.
}
```

And given the following payload class (that will be sent to a Spring controller):

```
public class Payload {
    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty(value = "orgId")
    private String orgId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty(value = "isInitialized")
    private Boolean isInitialized;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonProperty(value = "vehicle")
    private BaseVehicle vehicle;

    // Constructors, getters & setters down here
}
```

I'm wondering if its possible to have the Spring controller (using Jackson for JSON serialization) configured to only expect a `BaseVehicle` instance in the `Payload` it receives, but to dynamically infer which `BaseVehicle` subclass was actually sent:

```
@RequestMapping(value='/payload', method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody MyAppResponse onPayload(@RequestBody Payload payload) {
    logger.info("Received a payload with a vehicle of type: " + payload.getVehicle().getClass().getName());
}
```

So that if I happen to send a `Payload` JSON that contains a `Motorcycle` as its `vehicle` field, then when that `logger.info(...)` statement fires, the code sees the `vehicle` is a `Motorcycle` (and ditto for any other `BaseVehicle` subclass)?

**Is this possible, if so, how?**

Comment: Without additional information in the son I doubt it. Jackson needs to know somehow which type to create. Without specific information or extension it doesn't know that.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum (+1) - if providing extra information in the JSON is the *only* solution here, I'd be interested in what that solution might look like. However I'd **greatly** prefer a solution that allows the JSON to remain as-is. Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb I don't think it's easy. Usually "abstract" elements JSON documents provide a special type mark property allowing the JSON deserializer to instantiate the element right. Another option is based on fact that your `BaseVehicle` subclasses have different structure (unique names, field types, etc) therefore you can keep your JSON as-is: having a JSON tree (probably in memory), it's possible to analyze the JSON tree, and "heuristically" instantiate a concrete element "inferring" its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I'd greatly prefer a solution that allows the JSON to remain as-is.

As I mentioned in my comment above, you could analyze the payload vehicle JSON object tree in order to make a little analysis trying to detect the payload element type.

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = BaseVehicleJsonDeserializer.class)
abstract class BaseVehicle {

    @JsonProperty
    private String make;

    @JsonProperty
    private String model;

}

@JsonDeserialize(as = Car.class)
final class Car
        extends BaseVehicle {
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = Motorcycle.class)
final class Motorcycle
        extends BaseVehicle {

    @JsonProperty
    private int numCylinders;

}
```

The trick here is the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. The `BaseVehicleJsonDeserializer` can be implemented as follows:

```java
final class BaseVehicleJsonDeserializer
        extends JsonDeserializer<BaseVehicle> {

    @Override
    public BaseVehicle deserialize(final JsonParser parser, final DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        final TreeNode treeNode = parser.readValueAsTree();
        final Class<? extends BaseVehicle> baseVehicleClass = Stream.of(treeNode)
                // Check if the tree node is ObjectNode
                .filter(tn -> tn instanceof ObjectNode)
                // And cast
                .map(tn -> (ObjectNode) tn)
                // Now "bind" the object node with if the object node can be supported by the resolver
                .flatMap(objectNode -> Stream.of(BaseVehicleTypeResolver.cachedBaseVehicleTypeResolvers).filter(resolver -> resolver.matches(objectNode)))
                // If found, just get the detected vehicle class
                .map(BaseVehicleTypeResolver::getBaseVehicleClass)
                // Take the first resolver only
                .findFirst()
                // Or throw a JSON parsing exception
                .orElseThrow(() -> new JsonParseException(parser, "Cannot parse: " + treeNode));
        // Convert the JSON tree to the resolved class instance
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
        return objectMapper.treeToValue(treeNode, baseVehicleClass);
    }

    // Known strategies here
    private enum BaseVehicleTypeResolver {

        CAR_RESOLVER {
            @Override
            protected Class<? extends BaseVehicle> getBaseVehicleClass() {
                return Car.class;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matches(final ObjectNode objectNode) {
                return !objectNode.has("numCylinders");
            }
        },

        MOTORCYCLE_RESOLVER {
            @Override
            protected Class<? extends BaseVehicle> getBaseVehicleClass() {
                return Motorcycle.class;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matches(final ObjectNode objectNode) {
                return objectNode.has("numCylinders");
            }
        };

        // Enum.values() returns array clones every time it's invoked
        private static final BaseVehicleTypeResolver[] cachedBaseVehicleTypeResolvers = BaseVehicleTypeResolver.values();

        protected abstract Class<? extends BaseVehicle> getBaseVehicleClass();

        protected abstract boolean matches(ObjectNode objectNode);

    }

}
```

As you can see, such an approach is more or less fragile and sophisticated, but it tries to make some analysis. Now, how it can be used:

```java
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Stream.of(
        "{\"orgId\":\"foo\",\"isInitialized\":true,\"vehicle\":{\"make\":\"foo\",\"model\":\"foo\"}}",
        "{\"orgId\":\"bar\",\"isInitialized\":true,\"vehicle\":{\"make\":\"bar\",\"model\":\"bar\",\"numCylinders\":4}}"
)
        .map(json -> {
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(json, Payload.class);
            } catch ( final IOException ex ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        })
        .map(Payload::getVehicle)
        .map(BaseVehicle::getClass)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

> class q43138817.Car
>   class q43138817.Motorcycle